# ways to implement Rijndael-256 ECB in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rijndael, ecb

What are the ways to implement Rijndael-256 with ECB mode in Java?
I've found some variants of AES but I need exactly Rijndael-256.

If there is already an answer to it, I would appreciate someone referring me to it
,since I haven't found any.

Comment: Thank you. 
just another question, since Sun doesn't have a supporting library for 256bit , does Android have?
cause ultimately I will integrate it to an android app.

Comment: AFAIK, the Android cryptographic API is built on  or is a fork of BouncyCastle, so this should be available there.

Comment: thank you :) 
I'll look it up